# Is there anybody who could explain in details (in simple language) some code that uses Reflection and Linq A LOT

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I was following a blog which had extensive use of reflection, I understood the bigger picture, which was how to implement IDataErrorInfo that will look at data annotation to find out whether there is an error, and it’s generic. 
I tried it and it works great, and helps me get rid of tons of code. But I am struggling to understand one part of the code which uses reflection and Linq together, it is beyond my skills. Therefore I’d like to ask somebody to please explain to me in simple language what this few lines of code (each meathod) do. Do not worry about the wpf side of it, as I understand that, just the code that is involved in here

```
    private Dictionary<string, Func<ValidationBase, object>> propertyGetters;
    private Dictionary<string, ValidationAttribute[]> validators;

    private void Validate()
    {
        validators = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => GetValidations(p).Length !=  0).ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => GetValidations(p));
        propertyGetters = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => GetValidations(p).Length != 0).ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => GetValueGetter(p));
    }

    private ValidationAttribute[] GetValidations(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return (ValidationAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);
    }

    private Func<ValidationBase, object> GetValueGetter(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return viewmodel => property.GetValue(viewmodel, null);
    }
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Maybe narrow down the code to exactly what you're having a problem with?

Comment: it seems like he doesnt have a problem, he just doesnt understand some piece of code he found at the internet

Comment: @MathiasS. exactly this, i dont understand it

Comment: @dav_i the worst part to understand is everything from private void Validate() down to the end.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Please edit your question to focus on a certain aspect. There is too much at the moment for this to be a fit question.

Comment: @dav_i thanks for your reply. I left the worst bit in, i tried to go through a break points, and see it. But this code is not easy to step through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added comments to the code you supplied, which should hopefully explain more clearly what is going on:

```
private void Validate()
{
    validators = GetType()
                    // get all the properties
                    .GetProperties()
                    // where there are validation attributes
                    .Where(p => GetValidations(p).Length !=  0)
                    // and return a dictionary with the name of the property
                    // and an array of validation attributes
                    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => GetValidations(p));

    propertyGetters = GetType()
                    // get all the properties
                    .GetProperties()
                    // where there are validation attributes
                    .Where(p => GetValidations(p).Length != 0)
                    // and return a dictionary with the name of the property
                    // and a method which calls the getter of that property
                    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => GetValueGetter(p));
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of validation attributes for supplied property
/// </summary>
private ValidationAttribute[] GetValidations(PropertyInfo property)
{
    return (ValidationAttribute[])
                property.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(ValidationAttribute), 
                    true);
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the getter for the supplied property
/// </summary>
private Func<ValidationBase, object> GetValueGetter(PropertyInfo property)
{
    return viewmodel => property.GetValue(viewmodel, null);
}
```

As you can see, there is some duplication in the code, which can be removed, and the code can be more descriptive:

```
private void Validate()
{
    var properties = GetType().GetProperties();
    var propertiesWithValidators = (from property in properties
                                   let validations = property.GetValidations(property)
                                   where validations.Any()
                                   select 
                                   new 
                                   { 
                                       Property = property, 
                                       Validations = validations 
                                   }).ToArray();

    validators = propertiesWithValidators.ToDictionary(
                    pwv => pwv.Property.Name, 
                    pwv => pwv.Validations);

    propertyGetters = propertiesWithValidators.ToDictionary(
                        pwv => pwv.Property.Name, 
                        pwv => GetValueGetter(pwv.Property));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It helps, it looks like I have to spend some time, to learn reflection etc. As it is complicated code for me. As for the second part, i think I'll stay with the longer code untill I know more about. I accept this answer.